# User registration fields: default value

Tags: users, 6

I am trying to set the default values for the *Username*, *Email address*, *Password*, and *Confirm password* fields so that I can use JavaScript code to show the default values in the field, until the user enters the field and begins typing.

Do I need to use `hook_form_alter()` for this, or can I just add something to the template.php file for my theme?